# How to set one FK (foreign key) on several tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have several `Posts` tables and one `Votes` table. How can I prevent inserting non-existing `post_id` (in `Posts` tables) in the `Votes` table?

```
// Posts_1                  // Posts_2                  // Posts_3
+----+---------+            +----+---------+            +----+---------+
| id | content |            | id | content |            | id | content |
+----+---------+            +----+---------+            +----+---------+

// Votes
+----+---------+
| id | post_id |
+----+---------+
```

It should be noted, in reality the structure of `Posts` tables is different. (all `Posts` tables have not the same structure), Then I can not combine all `Posts` tables as one table.

Now I want to prevent of inserting invalid rows in the `Votes` table. (invalid = `post_id` is not exist in the none of `Posts` tables)

So, If I have just one table, I can create a foreign key on the `Votes.post_id` reference to `Posts.id`, But the problem is having several `Posts` table. ok, well, Is there any suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table structure is crazy. You need to have a POST Index Table, which combines all the posts to one single place and gives it like this:

```
// Posts_Index
+----+---------+------------+
| id | post_id | post_table |
+----+---------+------------+

// Votes
+----+---------+
| id | post_id |
+----+---------+
```

Else you need to reverse map the way. So that, `post_id -> votes.id`.

Comment: @Sajad I have the same model with me. I did that way. `:)`

Comment: sorry for asking, but `post_table` is containing of what? the `id` of each `Posts` table?

Comment: Well, it is like this. Combination key of which table and post id.

Comment: I feel your way is a correct, and I understood it several min ago, but now, I can not implement it.. . look, should I set a number for each `Posts` table (`1`, `2`,`3`) = (`Posts_1`, `Posts_2`, `Posts_3`). and store that number in `post_table` column. ok well, now how can I prevent inserting non-existing `post_id`?

Comment: First you insert in one of the three post table, next you insert in the post_index table, where there's no check for this alone, then you insert in the votes table, where you have a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Welcome @Sajad... `:)`

Comment: that is interesting, you use of the smile shape as code `;)` !!

Comment: @Sajad Hacking Smileys.

Comment: oh just one thing, for creating `Posts_Index` tables, there is any particular approach? or should I create it as normal?

Comment: Just normal buddy... `:)`

Comment: One thing: Is it better to I create a `VIEW` instead of a `TABLE` in this case? Because the posts will be increase always and I need to update *Posts_Index* table ..., So `VIEW` or `TABLE`?

Comment: Wow @Shafizadeh, You are messaging after like 3 months! `:P` View is better.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I don't know, I read in documentation which `VIEW` will be created according to the logic every time when a statement is executed that references the view. So, it I think it needs to a lot of processing. Now my last question: A `VIEW` is better or a `TABLE` and multiple `TRIGGER` on each Posts-table for create a new row in that table after insert in each Posts-table?

Comment: View is better again.

Comment: then, How should I fill `post_table` column in View?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be that you use post_table_ref in votes table to identify from which table the post has been voted for. This `post_table_ref` must be fixed for the whole application.

Depending on table from which post is coming from, you'll have to give `post_table_ref` in you votes update query.

E.g: if the post is coming from `post_table_01` you'll have to set `post_table_ref` to 1 in votes update query. At the time of getting records from votes table you'll use the same `post_table_ref` in `WHERE` clause of your `SELECT FROM VOTES` query.

Comment: Can you please explain how is this solution different from mine?

Comment: My solution doesn't require additional table hence less resource-intensive on server and also both updated and select queries will be simpler.

Comment: Both the solutions are same.

Comment: Your solution is good, but it is a bit duplicate. however there is several small difference (like your column name has `_ref` more than Praveen Kumar's answer - just kedding), anyway thanks for your attention, and +1 upvote for you.

Comment: and my question is *how can I prevent inserting non-existing post_id ?*

Comment: @PraveenKumar you told your answer with this answer are the same. can you explain me, how this prevents inserting non-existing `post_id`? In other word, how can prevent inserting non-existing `post_id` without using `Posts_Index` table?

Comment: Please explain! In my solution there is no situation of inserting nonexistent post_id

Comment: Oh okay... Sorry I guess I misunderstood then. Fine.

Comment: what do you mean of "there is no situation of inserting non-existing `post_id`" ? Imagine me manually add a row (while its `post_id` is not exist in the none of `Posts` tables.), so? I need to database does not let me.

Comment: You shouldn't have marked an answer right before implementing it.

Comment: I marked it as my answer when he explained me and I understood all of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't in this data structure, because you don't have one primary key to reference, but three, which can have the same value multiple times in different tables.

Using a FK column for each posts_# table can have your Votes referencing no or multiple posts_# tables.

If you -really- need 3 or more different posts tables, you could create one central post_base table with PK and let the other posts tables reference it.

Table posts_base:

```
Id int primary key,
-- possibly other common data
```

then give the posts_# tables the posts_base.Id as FK and let Votes.post_id reference posts_base.Id!

Also, read some books about relational database design first; it's rather easy to create tables with somethin in it, but without knowing about foreign keys, normalization and the like, the database quickly becomes a messy trash dump, which can neither meet performance nor data integrity requirements.

Or, if you don't need it or want to code all that yourself (easier in the beginning than learning relational DB design, but troublesome later on), shift to NoSQL, where you just dump posts as documents and add Votes to these documents when submitted (so they can never be orphaned).