# How to create a table containing post_id and post_table columns comprised of several other tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have three table like these:

```
// Posts_1                  // Posts_2                  // Posts_3
+----+---------+            +----+---------+            +----+---------+
| id | content |            | id | content |            | id | content |
+----+---------+            +----+---------+            +----+---------+
| 1  | hello   |            | 1  | how are |            | 1  | you     |
+----+---------+            +----+---------+            +----+---------+
```

Now I need to create a table named `Posts_Index` like this:

```
// Posts_index
+----+---------+------------+
| id | post_id | post_table |
+----+---------+------------+
| 1  | 1       | 1          |
| 2  | 1       | 2          |
| 3  | 1       | 3          |
+----+---------+------------+
```

I can do that using php (fetching all rows and then inserting them in the `Posts_index` table), But because in reality those tables are really big, using php for doing that takes much times. Now I want to know can I do that just using MySQL?

Comment: a few ways. One way is to explicitly create the table, then do an `insert into Posts_index(post_id,post_table) select (your join chunk here)`

Comment: but most importantly, don't have a new table per post

Comment: @Drew why? I need to that, because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677795/how-to-set-one-fk-foreign-key-on-several-tables

Comment: my first comment above was a generic one, until I looked further, and realized you have a bad design. I will look at your link

Comment: ok I looked. The accepted answer of there (by you), started by saying `The table structure is crazy.` But like you said to Gordon, you have a reason. So I am off to another question. good luck !

Comment: @Drew yes I know it is a bad structure, but really I can not change it. anyway thanks for your attention.

Comment: as long as you know, that if it is under your control, you can. If it is some external issue from another party, you probably can't. Just don't confuse `can't` with `won't`   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bad data structure and should combine the three tables into one.  However, what you want to do is easy enough:

```
create table Posts_Index (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    post_id int,
    post_table int
);

insert into Posts_Index(post_id, post_table)
    select id, 1
    from posts_1;

insert into Posts_Index(post_id, post_table)
    select id, 2
    from posts_2;

insert into Posts_Index(post_id, post_table)
    select id, 3
    from posts_3;
```

Why is this a bad idea?  Because in order to use `Post_Index` you will have to generate dynamic SQL -- or a rather complicated SQL expression.  It would be much better to combine the three tables into a single `Posts` table, unless you have a really, really, really good reason for keeping them separate.

In addition, you cannot specify proper foreign key relationships between the tables.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I have a really good reason for keeping them separate, My reason is the difference in structure.  And exactly for specifying  a foreign key I want to create `Posts_Index` table.

Comment: According to what you said *(You have a bad data structure and should combine the three tables into one)* I want to ask a question. please take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/e2c98a1b93088f0c3d59) and tell me separated tables are better or combined table ?

Comment: One table is probably better for that.  You can then define foreign key relationships to the entity, which appears to be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Adding little more on Gordon's answer; another straight forward way is to use `UNION` like

```
insert into Posts_Index(post_id, post_table)

select id, 1
from posts_1

 UNION ALL

select id, 2
from posts_2

UNION ALL

select id, 3
from posts_3
```

Comment: @Rahul . . . You should always use `union all` in these circumstances, because `union` incurs the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Duly Noted and edited. I was thinking probably he doesn't want any duplicates.